Ensuring the Privacy of Credit Card Details in Web Development (Frontend)
I want to hide the user's credit card details and ensure that they don't appear in the Inspect Element or other tools, for privacy purposes. It might seem like a basic question, but I just want to make sure I'm doing it correctly.
Below is the sample output.

What I did is:

Completely deleted the element with its value e.g. <p>171</p>
Replace it with <p class="data-mask"><p/>
Created a class name .data-mask
.data-mask { background-color: gray; padding: 5px; }

This solution is for CSS only, I wonder if its possible with JavaScript?

This question is more suitable for [security.se].

These details should never even be sent across and hidden on the front end itself, your front end should not have to worry about this. It should only display the card if the user entered it (at which point you cant hide it really anyway), and otherwise it should not even be there.

I am not totally clear what you are proposing, but the front end should never contain the full card details, other than at the point the user types them in. They must be checked against what the user has typed in elsewhere.
